# Is there any way to change the font size for Chart title, Legend and the data label?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

**Is there any way to change the font size for Chart title, Legend and the data label?**

The problem facing is our team are using the library "phpspreadsheet"([link to library github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)) to generate some excel files with chart and find out the font size of the chart title, the data legend and the data label is too small.

(please see screenshot attached.)

[The screenshot for the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPD4T.jpg)

I have searched the documentation and sample from the library but seems there is none mentioned how to change it.

Thanks all if there is any suggestion on this.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet this one you mean?

Comment: yes , i should modify the question for more clear :) thanks

Comment: From what I see in my project I make a new `Chart()` class which accepts as a second parameter a `Title()` class, which has a second parameter a `Layout()` class. But I can't find any additional configurations on the layout, so my best guess is that the library doesn't support it.

Comment: It is sad , May i know that if there is any alternative to generate/modify the excel file with chart to make styling on the other two things? Thanks all for helping :)

Comment: If you use the `Xlsx()` writer you can create your own writer and use it instead. Sad thing is there are some private properties, so it might not work with extending. But parts of the generating of the file is done with XML code, so if you have the time it might be easy to add the necessary tags to format and customize.

Comment: At least there is a way to go on instead of the dead end. Thanks :D

Comment: are you using one of the provided templates to generate the xlsx file?

Comment: yes , i am using the sample "33_Chart_create_pie.php" and modified something for my project need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing is, that XLSX files are zipped XML files.

What the PhpSpreadsheet is doing, is using pre-made XML templates to fill it with the data you would like to see on the XLSX, then zip the whole stuff, and name it XLSX.

If you wanna change the font size, then you have to find the right place in the used template. Luckily the PhpSpreadsheet provides a lot of samples in the `phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\samples\Chart` folder. If you execute the `32_Chart_read_write.php`, it will create 1 file from each template and gives you the paths.

The templates are located here: `phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\samples\templates`

If you unzip it you will see 3 folders filled with XML files. The one which responsible for the styles is most likely the `xl\styles.xml` file. The size should be in a  tag and it's also a tag with a name of `sz`. For example:

```
<sz val="23.5"/>
```

Here you modify the size of the font, then zip it back to XLSX and save it wherever you want and use it as it is provided in the samples.

Comment: Thanks :) I will try to diff the unzip excel folders to see which files are changes.

Comment: for whom may be interested, the style for chart is stored in the chart related xml files.

Please find the tag `<c:legendEntry>` for legend

and find the tag `<c:txPr>` for labels